# Using Querying Language Vs Java To determine information

Tags: java, sql, database

I have an application written in Java where I am accessing data from an SQL database. In a few particular scenarios I have the ability to Query the database for information or I could write code in java to obtain the data i need based off of objects that are in scope. My question is this, is it more efficient to use queries when possible or write java code to achieve what is needed. Maybe a specific scenario would help.

I have a scenario where I query the database in order to get a list. After that i write some JAVA code to select only one of those particular objects from the list. In this scenario i used java to establish the object i needed.

An alternative would be to query the database and in my query join two tables together and only return the one object that is needed. In this scenario I would use a Querying language to establish the object i needed.

Any Tips or advice would be appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think this way. `SQL queries are much closer to data` than java code. Also java needs to load all the data to perform filtering. **If you can write efficient SQL, SQL is always better than Java.**

Java filtering is preferable in the scenarios where lot of computation and business logic is involved. I personally prefer writing complex business logic in Java when compared to database.

Answer (score 1):

Quering a database is fast as databases are designed in this respect.
Also you will get only the required information in your java code so that you don't need any extra memory for other non-useable objects.

Answer (score 1):

It is usually the case that a database will handle queries faster than using Java to filter through a list. The only good time to use application code is if the filtering requirements are so complex that it cannot be expressed in a query language (highly unlikely), or if you would end up having to query the database many times to get what you need.

Both of these can be fixed by sitting down and focusing on designing intelligent queries, again resulting in the database winning out.

Answer (score 1):

Your's is a question with a few vagaries, so it's hard to be specific.

In general, optimizing too early isn't the way to go.  You may be best off coding things in the most straightforward manner, and then use the resulting information to decide on what improvements are necessary.

### Hypothetical #1

The resulting list from the SQL query is huge.  In this case, it's better to use SQL to limit the results.

### Hypothetical #2

The resulting list is small.  Probably doesn't affect performance much which way you do it, but using Java to manipulate the list after the fact would make the code more complicated.

### Hypothetical #3

Either of the above scenarios, but the underlying data doesn't change very often, or is requested often.  You could cache the data, make copies in Java and manipulate those copies to sort them, filter them, etc.  Might be faster in some circumstances, but results in more complicated code.

### Hypothetical #4

Resulting list isn't very large, but is the result of a complicated and slow performing query.  Perhaps cache the result, and when you need variants on the data (filtered or sorted) use Java to copy the cached list and sort and/or filter the copy of the list.  Or create a materialized view in the database and query that instead.